# Поэлементное переключение recyclerView

Tags: java, recyclerview, kotlin

Синий - recyclerView.
Оранжевый - элементы recyclerView.
Прямоугольник - область отображаемая пользователю.

Как реализовать так, чтобы элементы не останавливались на экране(не видно было стыков),а менялись сразу по свайпу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так вопрос в стыках или в докрутке? Потому что одно с другим не связано, стыки решаются разметкой.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Мне нужно за один свайп на экране отображать только строго один элемент. Сейчас я могу прокрутить rv и оставить в таком положении как на картинке.

Comment: @nuqss, вам или ViewPager нужен или прикрутить LinearSnapHelper

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Спасибо. SnapHelper snapHelperStart = new GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.START);
snapHelperStart.attachToRecyclerView(startRecyclerView);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SnapHelper snapHelperStart = new GravitySnapHelper(Gravity.START);  
snapHelperStart.attachToRecyclerView(startRecyclerView);
```